# How to normalize database with tree structure MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, tree-structure

I want to organize my Mangas, each Manga will have many Chapters, each Chapter will have many pages, between 20 pages.

Tree : Mangas -> Chapters -> Pages.

I want to add the Manga, instead, add each Chapter with many Pages to the manga created.

How do you do that? How to normalize the database with tree structure?

Comment: What do you think is the answer?

Comment: Normalize? Parent to Child, Child to Child?

Comment: Sounds like approximately the right idea

Comment: How would you solve this? Answer this thread to close it.

Comment: If there are exactly 3 levels to this "tree", don't approach it as a tree, simply have 3 tables and 2 1:many relationships.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.